# Is it possible to limit the number of GPU cores in new MacBooks M series?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, performance, osx

I am using blender 4.1 with a MacBook M3.
I am rendering using the CLI and while rendering some scenes I would like to keep using the computer to do some other stuff, so I was wondering if there is any way to limit the number of GPU cores that blender uses while rendering.

I am not hurry with the render process, so I would like to avoid overheating the computer. After a couple of minutes of ~100% GPU usage the computer's fans sound as if the computer is going to take off.

Without any configuration blender takes ~100% of GPU cores.
I tried changing the number of threads, but this seem to modify CPU threads and not GPU ones.
Also I tried to play with the tile size, but with small tiles still blender ends up using 100% of the GPU.
[image]

I can switch to CPU instead of rendering on GPU, and limit the threads, but this is super inefficient because GPU cores are much more faster than CPU ones. At 20% capacity using GPU cores it still render much faster than using 100% of CPU cores.

Thanks!